# Unable to compile MeshLab from source on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: compilation, meshlab

I've downloaded the MeshLab sources and updated my Qt installation to the latest (Qt Creator 4.2.0 built on Dec 9, 2016).  On my first attempt to compile the meshlab_full project I found that I had to rename the io_txt folder under plugins_experimental to io_TXT.  But after that it fails with this error:

> In file included from ../../src/common/meshmodel.h:32:0,
>                    from ../../src/common/filterparameter.cpp:32: ../../src/common/ml_mesh_type.h:4:33: fatal error:
>   vcg/complex/complex.h: No such file or directory  #include
>   
>                                    ^ compilation terminated.

Indeed there is no vcg folder.  How do I get it?

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 2):

You need to get vcg lib. It must be at the same level than your meshlab directory :

```
yourdevelfolder/
 |
 ├──meshlab
 │   ├──docs
 │   ├──README.md
 │   ├──src
 │   ├──...
 │   └──...
 └──vcglib
     ├──apps
     ├──doc
     ├──eigenlib
     ├──...
     └──...
```

Than you must get vgclib sources :

```
$ git clone https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/vcglib.git
$ cd vcglib
$ git checkout devel
```

Instructions for compilation are [there](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/tree/master/src/README.md)

Comment: Thanks Eric - I appreciate the help  ;)

I downloaded the vcg files and put them in the correct place, then built the external.pro project.  That got me past the error I was seeing before but still can't build meshlab full or mini.  The error I get says "error: ‘ColorConverter’ has not been declared".  I've done a fair amount of poking around and can't tell if ColorConverter is a Qt thing or a MeshLab thing.  Do you have any insights?  Thanks, Rich

Comment: Give some detailed logs. vcglib is maybe not in the good location. The main problem I met with vcglib was that I did not checkout to devel branch.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Eric - I had to find a suitable method for sharing the compiler output.  Here it is:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2i1fbB8wvDySnVZMzMzVTZXQU0/view?usp=sharing   Thanks!

Comment: Rename `meshlab-2016.12` directory to `meshlab`. You must find `meshlab` and `vcglib` directories in `/home/rich/Downloads/3dTools/MeshLab/Source`.    

Here is a log from my compilation :

`cd common/ && ( test -e Makefile || /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/bin/qmake /home/eric/dev/3D/meshlab/meshlab/src/common/common.pro -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile 
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/eric/dev/3D/meshlab/meshlab/build-meshlab_full-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/common »`

Comment: Thanks again @Eric.  That got me farther down the path, but now I have a different error.  Compile output:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2i1fbB8wvDyOWJFQjA4NGt0dG8/view?usp=sharing   Here is my folder structure:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2i1fbB8wvDyZXNPdjBKbmlNSlU/view?usp=sharing   I need to continue in a different comment...

Comment: It says it cannot find -ljhead.  I'm not an expert at compiling but it looks like it's looking for jhead in the /home/rich/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib folder, right?  There is none there but there is a libjhead.a in /home/rich/MeshLab/meshlab/src/build-external-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Release/lib/linux-g++   and there is a jhead.o in /home/rich/MeshLab/meshlab/src/build-external-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Release/jhead-2.95   Any idea what I have wrong?

Comment: Compiled librairies must be copied manually to `meshlab/src/external/lib/linux-g++`. You may have problems when compiling with "Shadow Build' checked. I fixed the issue with this commit : https://github.com/eboudrand/meshlab/commit/1e8f64b3457f3fddef1cd081d7d47e40f0d8c728

Comment: Success!  Thank you @Eric Boudrand!   I appreciate all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

As commented by @AlessandroMuntoni , we can use `--recursive` option, and VCG would automatically be available as a submodule:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab
```

#### Original post

In `meshlab.pro` it is commented:

```
# MESHLAB_SOURCE_DIRECTORY: the directory where is placed the main meshlab.pro
```

In `general.pri` it is set:

```
# VCG directory
VCGDIR = $$MESHLAB_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/../vcglib
```

Therefore, I forked and cloned the [VCG library](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/vcglib) inside:

```
 |
 └──meshlab (Git clone)
     ├──docs
     ├──README.md
     ├──src (`meshlab.pro` is inside this)
     ├──...
     ├──...
     └──vcglib (Git clone)
```

It worked for me =)

Comment: Now, vcglib is a submodule of meshlab. When cloning meshlab, you just need to use the flag `--recursive`.